# OpenStreetMap to Opendrive map format

Tags: openstreetmap, xml

I am trying to generate opendrive (xodr) files from the OpenStreetMap data.
OpenStreetMap provides nodes and ways. In opendrive I need to compute the length of roads, heading angle, inertial x and y coordinates and the geometry records for the roads. Right now I am using `osmnx` module to visualize the road network.

Can I get some help regarding the generation of geometry records?

Answer (score 0):

OSMnx computes the length of streets automatically and saves as the edges' `length` attribute. Road geometry is the `geometry` edge attribute. Heading angle is computed using `ox.add_edge_bearings` and x,y coordinates are attributes of the two nodes incident on each edge.

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, CA, USA', network_type='drive')
G = ox.add_edge_bearings(G)
gdf_nodes, gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, fill_edge_geometry=True)
```